# How to get the body part from the mail using MIME::Parser?

Tags: perl, cpan

```
use MIME::Parser;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

$parser = MIME::Parser->new( );
$parser->output_to_core(1); # don't write attachments to disk

while (<STDIN>) {
$MESSAGE .= $_;
}

$message = $parser->parse_data($MESSAGE); # die( )s if can't parse

$head = $message->head( ); # object--see docs
$preamble = $message->preamble; # ref to array of lines
$epilogue = $message->epilogue; # ref to array of lines

$num_parts = $message->parts;
for (my $i=0; $i < $num_parts; $i++) {
    print "part number = $i\n";
    my $part = $message->parts(1);
    my $content_type = $part->mime_type;
    my $body = $part->as_string;
    print $body;
}
```

In the output i can see content headers as well. Do we have any process to have only the message body content collecteed into array?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you read STDIN into $MESSAGE? Why not just $parser->parse(\\*STDIN) ??

Answer (score 3):

`my $body = $part->as_string;` is wrong. A MIME part (`$part` is an instance of class [MIME::Entity](http://p3rl.org/MIME%3a%3aEntity)) is comprised of headers and body and epilogue.

This should instead be either `my @body_encoded_lines = $part->body` (list of lines) or `my $body_decoded_handle = $part->bodyhandle` (instance of [MIME::Body](http://p3rl.org/MIME%3a%3aBody)).